# Couchbase missing Analytics, Eventing and Running Queries

Tags: analytics, couchbase, sql++

I'm new to Couchbase and trying to understand the features of community edition. I can't find analytics, eventing and running queries that I see in examples and tutorials. Nowhere says that these are enterprise features, so I'm asking myself if there are something missing in my setup. Asking help!

Answer (score 2):

Analytics and Eventing are currently Enterprise only features. See: https://www.couchbase.com/products/editions

Querying (non Analytics querying) with N1QL, however, is available in Community edition.

When you first install Couchbase, the query service should be checked by default. It's possible that you unchecked it by mistake.

Comment: Thanks. I missed this info.